# 405 method not allowed error coming while posting data from form in Laravel 5.4 backpack Admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am making simple form of adding news in Laravel 5.4 backpack admin just to have overview of Laravel 5.4 but got stuck while posting data from News form located at news/add view. Though I am sending action to News Controller at add method but it is showing 405 method not allowed error. Please check my code below and let me know what is the issue in it. Might be I am doing some silly mistake, sorry if that is the case.

View : add.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'NewsController@add']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="title">Title:</label>
<input name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="description">Description:</label>
<textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control">
</textarea>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submitBtn" 
value="Submit">Submit</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller : NewsController.php

```
public function add(){
echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->data->request); die;
return view("news.add");
}
```

[image: <code>405 method not allowed error coming while posting data from form in Laravel 5.4 backpack Admin</code>]

Comment: Please attach the list of routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly add this in top in your Controller:-

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
```

After that your function should have this parmeter Request $request:-

```
public function add(Request $request){
   $data = $request->all();
   return view("news.add");
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like method in the route file is not `POST`.

Change your route like this :

```
Route::post('/addnews',['as' => 'news.add', 'uses'=>'NewsController@add']);
```

I would recommend you to use named route. It will be easy to use.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'news.add']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'add')) !!}
    // your form fields
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Your route will be:

```
Route::post('/add','NewsController@add');
```

Hope it helps..